# How to set a log4j logs level in heroku variable configuration?

Tags: variables, heroku, log4j2

I have a `log4j2.xml` file for my java app that I deploy in heroku.

And for the Log level i'm having :

```
<Property name="level">${sys:LOG4J_LEVEL:-info}</Property>
```

How can I set a heroku variable but still calling it from this xml file ?

On heroku :

```
LOG4J_LEVEL : DEBUG
```

How to use it on `log4j2.xml` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is an environment variable you can add an environment variable to your Heroku App and let it retrieve the value there.

Set the key to `LOG4J_LEVEL` and the value to `DEBUG`

[image]